# What does '/p:' on the Windows Command Line mean

Tags: asp.net, windows, shell, command-line

I want to name the environment in the command line when using dotnet publish. I found this solution

```
dotnet publish -o site /p:EnvironmentName=Production
```

I've never seen that /p: argument before and want to know what exactly that is. I tried to google it but because of its syntax it was hard to find anything.

I especially want to know if I can use this command also on a Linux machine in bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, it is passed to MSBuild and sets a variable/property called `EnvironmentName` to a value `Production`. Then MSBuild scripts can read that variable when performing various tasks. It's moreless the same as setting a property in `<PropertyGroup>` in MSBuild script (also VisualStudio's cpsroj file).

You can see it [for example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2022#set-properties-from-the-command-line)

```
msbuild buildapp.csproj -t:HelloWorld -p:Configuration=Release
```

Note that `-p:` syntax is the same as `/p:` (also `-t:` and `/t:` and so on). The former is the new one, while the latter conforms to old "DOS" way of providing command line options in Windows. For quite a couple of years many newer developer tools from Microsoft accept both ways, but the `-` is preferred, as it can also be used in i.e. powershell or linux, while the older `/` can't (or can, but cause some problems or need complicated escaping/quoting).

EDIT: ah yes, and I didn't fully answer.. The `-p` or `/p` is NOT a "windows commandline thing". In your example, this is a parameter for the `dotnet` program, and what I described above is true only because `dotnet` happens to later call into `msbuild` program. if you spot such `-p`/`/p` parameter anywhere else, in any other application, then it may do something completely  different.

Lastly, on Linux - yes, you can use it with `dotnet` toolset on Linux as well (net core, mono, etc) ((and I'd strongly suggest using `-p:` version)). However, same rules apply. As long as it is used with this app called `dotnet`, it will have the effect of setting environmentname during build. In any other case, or any other app, such parameter can have other meanings. It's all app-dependent, be it on Windows, or Linux.