# How to pass complex arguments to msbuild in bash?

Tags: bash, msbuild, code-coverage

If I run this in Powershell it works:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage="true" /p:CoverletOutputFormat="lcov" /p:Exclude="[*]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generated.*"
```

When I try to run it in a bash shell I change the `/p` to `//p` to escape them so it looks like this:

```bash
dotnet test //p:CollectCoverage="true" //p:CoverletOutputFormat="lcov" //p:Exclude="[*]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generated.*"
```

But for whatever reason it doesn't like the:

`//p:Exclude="[*]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generated.*"`

It responds with `MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.` does anyone else have experience with this and know how to get bash to correctly parse the Exclude value?

If I make it simpler so it doesn't have any square braces or wildcards in it, like this:

`//p:Exclude="System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generated"`

It doesn't complain, but then it doesn't do what I need it to.

Comment: I don't work with `dotnet` so fwiw ... I ran a web search on *dotnet AND bash AND "/p"* and of the various hits these two - [this](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9751) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609989)   - show some promise; gist of the (possible) solutions: wrap in escaped double quotes [ `\"/p:PackageVersion=1.0.0-dev\"` ] or replace `/p` with `-p` [ `-p:Configuration=Release` ]; I'd probably also try replacing the escaped double quotes with (non-escaped) single quotes

Comment: using -p solved all the issues, thank you

Comment: There is no point to "escape" a `/` in bash. If you write a double slash, the `dotnet` program will see two slashes. Write a single slash if you want `dotnet` to see a single slash.

Comment: Note however that using your approach, `dotnet` won't see the double quotes. Since I don't know Powershell and its quoting rules, I can't say whether this behaviour is the same their.

Comment: It would help if you would specify, what argument strings `dotnet` should receive.